# multiple javascript in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having trouble loading multiple javascripts in HTML page. Here is the code it is for the txtlzr and spin effect. . The spinner function name is "rotation" and the txtlzr function name is "rr"

```
 <html>
 <head>
   <title></title>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://raw.github.com/krisk/textualizer/master/textualizer.min.js"></script>
   <style type="text/css">
     #txtlzr { font-size: 150px; width: 960px; height:250px; }
    </style>
 </head>
 <body onload: "rr(); rotation()";><div id="txtlzr"> </div> </body>

    <script>
    $(function rr() {
             var list = ['Text 1', 'Hello World', 'Screencasts'];
        var options = {
            duration: 1000,          // Time (ms) each blurb will remain on screen
            rearrangeDuration: 1000, // Time (ms) a character takes to reach its position
            effect: 'random',        // Animation effect the characters use to appear
            //centered: true           // Centers the text relative to its container
        }
        var txt = $('#txtlzr');
        txt.textualizer(list, options); // textualize it!
        txt.textualizer('start'); // start
    });

    </script>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">​
    <script  type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"        src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function rotation() {
        $("#image").rotate({
            angle: 0,
            animateTo: 360,
            callback: rotation,
            easing: function (x, t, b, c, d) { // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c:      change In value, d: duration
                return c * (t / d) + b;
            }
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function () {
        rotation();
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Just looking at it, you're including the jQuery source include (the googleapis line) *after* you've already run a jQuery block of code. Eh, scratch that, you're multiple including it (seeing the misformatted line at the very top).

Comment: Why are you including the jquery source twice?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: stackoverflow is not letting me insert the additional url script sources for the above code. The problem I am getting is running two of the functions at the same time. For some reason the google spinner only works but not the textualizer. I want both to work at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huge mess

1. put the scripts in the head
2. load jQuery once
3. rr was not a function but a mix of jQuery and plain JS
4. the HTML would never validate
5. do not use body onload when you have document.ready (and even then use window.onload instead if you do not have jQuery

try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gTRVB/)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://raw.github.com/krisk/textualizer/master/textualizer.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryrotate.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
      <script>
        function rotation() {
          $("#image").rotate({
            angle: 0,
            animateTo: 360,
            callback: rotation,
            easing: function (x, t, b, c, d) { // t: current time, b: begInnIng value, c:      change In value, d: duration
                return c * (t / d) + b;
            }
          });
        };

        function rr() {
          var list = ['Text 1', 'Hello World', 'Screencasts'];
          var options = {
            duration: 1000,          // Time (ms) each blurb will remain on screen
            rearrangeDuration: 1000, // Time (ms) a character takes to reach its position
            effect: 'random',        // Animation effect the characters use to appear
            //centered: true           // Centers the text relative to its container
          }
          var txt = $('#txtlzr');
          txt.textualizer(list, options); // textualize it!
          txt.textualizer('start'); // start
        };
        $(document).ready(function () {
          rr();
          rotation();
        });

      </script>
      <style type="text/css">
       #txtlzr { font-size: 150px; width: 960px; height:250px; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="txtlzr"> </div> 
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" id="image">​
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I prefer to be a star rather than start which is a tail in Dutch ;)))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you are better off using this instead of the `onload` attribute:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You end the body element too early, so the scripts are not inside the body. I'm not sure how all different browsers react to this, but they might ignore the scripts, or run the load event before the scripts are loaded.

Either way, move everything inside the body element, and it should work.